# How to access a variable in a class in a json

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an abstract class in fileA :

```
export abstract class BtAction {
  public name: string;
  public icon: string;
  public cmd: string;
  public cmdResponse: string;
  public successMsg: string;
  public errorMsg: string;
  public device: any;

  ...
}
```

And a JSON in fileB :

```
export const BtActionList = {
    open: class ActionOpen extends BtAction {
        constructor(toast: ToastController,
                    private ble: BLE) {
            super(toast);
            this.name = "Open";
            this.cmd =  "0x3A21";
            this.cmdResponse = "3a01";
            this.successMsg = "successMsg";
            this.icon = "log-in";
            this.errorMsg = "error";
        }

        ...
    },
    stock: class ActionStock extends BtAction {
        constructor(toast: ToastController,
                    private ble: BLE) {
            super(toast);
            this.name = "Stock";
            this.cmd =  "0x3A21";
            this.cmdResponse = "3a01";
            this.successMsg = "successMsg";
            this.icon = "log-in";
            this.errorMsg = "error";
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

My file C import `BtActionList` and i want to loop on it to display a tabsbar :

`import { BtActionList } from './utils/bt-action-list';`

But when i put a `console.log` i see nowhere my variable :

[Inspector of my Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYoxK.png)

How can i access to my variables ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't see any JSON in this question.

Comment: @Taplar FileB ? If it's not JSON, what is it ? :/

Comment: FileB is a variable that points to an object, with two properties, `open` and `stock`, both of which are classes.  JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) refers to a string that is syntatically formatted to be able to be parsed later.  None of this is JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you might want is this:

```js
export const BtActionList: {open: BtAction, stock: BtAction} = {
    open: {
        name: "Open",
        cmd:  "0x3A21",
        cmdResponse: "3a01",
        successMsg: "successMsg",
        icon: "log-in",
        errorMsg: "error"
    },
    stock: {
        name: "Stock",
        cmd:  "0x3A21",
        cmdResponse: "3a01",
        successMsg: "successMsg",
        icon: "log-in",
        errorMsg: "error"
    }
};
```

The way you had it right now, the classes are not instantiated and as a result aren't create to be able to access any variable on it. If you really want the class you can instantiate it like so:

```js
class ActionOpen extends BtAction {
    constructor(toast: ToastController,
                private ble: BLE) {
        super(toast);
        this.name = "Open";
        this.cmd =  "0x3A21";
        this.cmdResponse = "3a01";
        this.successMsg = "successMsg";
        this.icon = "log-in";
        this.errorMsg = "error";
    }
}

class ActionStock extends BtAction {
    constructor(toast: ToastController,
                private ble: BLE) {
        super(toast);
        this.name = "Stock";
        this.cmd =  "0x3A21";
        this.cmdResponse = "3a01";
        this.successMsg = "successMsg";
        this.icon = "log-in";
        this.errorMsg = "error";
    }
}

export const BtActionList = {
    open: new ActionOpen(/* pass in your initializers */),
    stock: new ActionStock(/* pass in your initializers */)
}
```